# Saving arraylist as SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I have a recyclerview with many elements that I want to save with SharedPreferences for when my app is closed and reopened. The code for my array is below.

```
public ArrayList<MyInformation> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList<MyInformation>();    
        return results;
    }
```

(I add stuff to the recyclerview with this in myAdapter)

```
public void addEntity(int i, MyInformation entity) {
        information.add(i, entity);
        notifyItemInserted(i);
    }
```

So, how would I save this array for when I close the app?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the question you are asking? Also try to make sure your english is correct, this is really hard to read

Comment: @MathieuBrouwers How do I save the elements in my recyclerview

Comment: Sorry. I was hurrying while posting this. Just ask me and I'll happily clear it up. :D

Comment: How you did this? you got success? If yes, please post solution as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save your list of data in sharedpreferences as String by using Gson.
Before doing that of course you need to add neccesarry dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

Then when you want to save, convert your array into String:

```
ArrayList<MyInformation> yourData = new ArrayList<MyInformation>();
String dataStr = new Gson().toJson(yourData);
```

To retrieve and convert back to an object is also simple:

```
String str = "";//you need to retrieve this string from shared preferences.

Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyInformation>>() { }.getType();
ArrayList<MyInformation> restoreData = new Gson().fromJson(str, type);
```

There you have it

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it now and report back to you.